# Adding hard disc to existing Samba Share folder

Tags: samba, debian

I have samba share running on a server sharing music, videos and files over network from a hdd. This hdd is now nearly full, now i would like to add another hdd of 5tb, so how can i do that without any additional changes on user side.

Greetings,
Sai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might create a new folder inside your samba share and mount the new 5TB disk in this new folder. Maybe not the most elegant solution, but is quick and easy one.

First you need to partition your disk as you see fit. You may find a lot of tutorials on Google (https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+partition+disk+in+linux).
I'll assume that you made only one partition on your new disk and that system sees your new disk as 'sdb' device (for more on identifying disks, please see https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+identify+hard+disk+in+%2Fdev+linux).

Create a folder called 'new_disk" in your samba share directory:

```
mkdir /path/to/samba_share/new_disk
```

Then edit your 'fstab' file (found in /etc/fstab):

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

and it might look similar to this:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

proc  /proc  proc  defaults  0  0
# /dev/sda5
UUID=be35a709-c787-4198-a903-d5fdc80ab2f8  /  ext4  relatime,errors=remount-ro  0  1
# /dev/sda6
UUID=cee15eca-5b2e-48ad-9735-eae5ac14bc90  none  swap  sw  0  0

/dev/scd0  /media/cdrom0  udf,iso9660  user,noauto,exec,utf8  0  0
```

And you need to add a mount point for your new hard disk. Add the following line to your /etc/fstab file:

```
/dev/sdb1  /path/to/samba_share/new_disk  ext4  defaults 0  0
```

Save the changes and mount the new disk manually (or reboot for automatic mount):

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /path/to/samba_share/new_disk
```

Make sure there is a new line at the end of the fstab file.

Adjust access rights to your new disk/folder as you see fit, and you should be ready to go.

Comment: This may work but how about explaining how to mound a drive to a folder ?

Comment: Good edit +1...